# Passing functor with templated parameters to template function

Tags: c++11, templates, c++14, functor, template-argument-deduction

I'm writing a function that takes a functor as an argument.  The arguments of the functor's call operator are templated. A very simplified version of what I'm trying to do is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <array>

template <const size_t N>
using CVec = std::array<double,N>;

template<const size_t N>
using ode_fun = std::function<CVec<N>(const CVec<N>&)>;

template<const size_t N>
void step( const CVec<N>& x, ode_fun<N> sys)
{
  sys(x);
}

struct foo_t
{
  CVec<2>  operator()( const CVec<2>& x_in)
  {
    CVec<2> xdot;

    std::cout << "x_in: [" << x_in[0] << ", " << x_in[1] << "]\n";

    return xdot;
  }
  CVec<2> x;
};

int main()
{
  foo_t foo;
  foo.x[0] = -.5;
  foo.x[1] = 1.0f;

  CVec<2> x;
  x[0] = 12.0;
  x[1] = 23.2;

  step(x, foo);
}
```

however when compiling, I get this error:

```
temp_arg_subs_fail.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
temp_arg_subs_fail.cpp:42:14: error: no matching function for call to ‘step(CVec<2>&, foo_t&)’
   step(x, foo);
              ^
temp_arg_subs_fail.cpp:12:6: note: candidate: template<long unsigned int N> void step(CVec<N>&, ode_fun<N>)
 void step( const CVec<N>& x, ode_fun<N> sys)
      ^~~~
temp_arg_subs_fail.cpp:12:6: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
temp_arg_subs_fail.cpp:42:14: note:   ‘foo_t’ is not derived from ‘std::function<std::array<double, N>(const std::array<double, N>&)>’
   step(x, foo);
              ^
```

However this works:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

using my_fn = std::function<int(int, int)>;

void summer(int x, int y, my_fn fn)
{
  std::cout << "summer: " << fn(x,y) << std::endl;
}

struct foo_t
{
  int operator()(int x, int y)
  {
    return x + y + z;
  }    
  int z = 0;    
};

int main ()
{    
  foo_t foo;
  foo.z = 5;    

  summer(3,4,foo);

  return 0;
}
```

Substantially, the only difference I can tell between the two is that one is templated and the other isn't. Is it because the step function in the first snippet is only a template and not instantiated or something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that `step()` require an `ode_fun<N>` object as second argument (that is a `std::function<std::array<double, N>(std::array<double, N> const &)>`) and `N` is to be deduced.

But if you pass `foo`, that is a `foo_t` object that can be converted to a `ode_fun<2>` but (this is the point) **isn't** a `ode_fun<2>` object, the compiler can't deduce the `N` value.

You can solve the problem in two obvious ways.

(1) pass a `ode_fun<2>` object to `step()`

```
ode_fun<2>  foo2 { foo };

step(x, foo2);
```

(2) or deduce a simple type `F` (as "functional") in `step()`, so all functional are deducible

```
template<const size_t N, typename F>
void step( const CVec<N>& x, F sys)
{
  sys(x);
}
```

> Is it because the step function in the first snippet is only a template and not instantiated or something else?

Exactly.

In your not-template example, `summer()` receive a `std::function<int(int, int)>`.

Nothing is to be deduced so, passing it a `foo_t` object that isn't a `std::function<int(int, int)>` but can be converted to it, the compiler convert `foo` to `std::function<int(int, int)>`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer--before asking I tried solution (2) which works fantastic.  I had also tried solution (1) by passing foo as `std::function<odefun<2> >(foo)` into the `step` function which didn't work (and which seems pretty obvious now why).  Wrapping it with simply `ode_fun<2>(foo)` and passing that into `step` works great.